# JAVA servlets - open message popup

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, servlets

I want to user HttpServletResponse object to compose a response that will tell the browser client to open a popup with some message - how can i do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every Servlet response is basically an Http doc/snippet. So you could return a call to a javascript function that will be executed on the client side. The function can be passed in that Servlet response or it can be pre-included in the .js file.

just an example:

```
//servlet code
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
response.setContentType("text/html");  
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
out.println("alert('deadbeef');");  
out.println("</script>");
```

Comment: There is a problem - the original page becomes blank - i want the content to stay and the message to just pop up

Comment: After clicking on OK it going to blank page but I want to stay in that page only How? I tries this after above code `resp.sendRedirect("./index.jsp");` but not getting alert

Answer (score 1):

Add to HttpServletResponse some Javascript code that will open a popup, something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popupWindow() {
    window.open( "someLinkToBePoppedUp" )
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you cannot do that directly. You must send in response some code (probably HTML and JS) which will instruct client browser to show message window, eg

```
String someMessage = "Error !";
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print("<html><head>");
out.print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(" + someMessage + ");</script>");
out.print("</head><body></body></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't.

Thanks to their popularity for annoying adverts, most browsers reject attempts to open popups that aren't a response to something the user does within a page.

If you just want to display messaging, you could just include it in a page, or output a [script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) with an [alert statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert) in it.